# Factorization of a Markov chain as the product of smaller chains

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, markov-chains

Consider a discrete-time Markov chain on $n$ states $S = \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$,  with transition dynamics

$$ \mathbf{x}^{(t+1)} = \mathbf{P} \mathbf{x}^{(t)},$$

where $\mathbf{P}$ is the *transition matrix*, a stochastic matrix (nonnegative entries and unit column sums). We are interested in the possibility of decomposing this chain into a product of 2 chains on two disjoint subject sets of states $A,B \subseteq S$ (of approx same size),
with dynamics $\mathbf{P}_A$ and $\mathbf{P}_B$ resp. so that

$$\mathbf{x}_A^{(t+1)} = \mathbf{P}_A \mathbf{x}_A^{(t)},\text{ and }\mathbf{x}_B^{(t+1)} = \mathbf{P}_B \mathbf{x}_B^{(t)}, $$

where $\mathbf{P}_A$ and $\mathbf{P}_B$ are stochastic matrices on $\#A$ and $\#B$ states resp. When we can produce such a factorization, we shall say that the original chain is splittable (index $r = 1$), otherwise it is irreducible (index $r = 0$).

**Question:** I wish to extend / relax this *split index* $r$ to a general scenario and get a float $r(\mathbf{P}) \in [0, 1]$ which measures how well / bad the original chain can be **approximated** can be factored into smaller chains. Is there anything in literature (maybe linear algebra ?, graph theory ?) that can shed light on this ?

Comment: It sounds as though you might be asking whether the original transition matrix can be approximated as a tensor product of two stochastic matrices. I guess whether such an approximation is useful would depend on the kind of question you want to apply it to.

Comment: 1. What is $\otimes$ here? The Kronecker product? If so, the condition $A,B\subseteq S$ seems weird. Maybe you mean $\oplus$? Please clarify. For instance, if you specified dimensions it would solve a lot of doubts. 2. Do not use the word irreducible -- it already means something else in Markov chains.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I've fixed the post to remove sources of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dynamical systems, there is a concept of "almost-invariance", which generalizes invariance of a set, under the action of dynamics. The analogy is roughly the following:

If you create a markov chain on $S$ from the given dynamics $F$, then if the chain is reducible (into $A$ and $B$), it just implies that sets $A$ and $B$ are invariant under the dynamics. This is detected e.g. if the second largest eigenvalue of the Markov matrix is 1.

If $\lambda_2<1$, the almost-invariance of a $\textbf{set}$ $C$ can be quantified by defining a scalar

$\rho(C)=\dfrac{m(F^{-1}(C)\cap C)}{m(C)}$, where $m$ is a lebesgue measure. Now, one can formulate an optimization problem to divide the set S into two sets A and B, such that the result minimizes

$r=\max (\rho(A),\rho(B))$. This metric might be closest thing to the number you are looking for.

This problem is NP-hard, however several heuristics give good results. 
See: Froyland, Gary. "Statistically optimal almost-invariant sets." Physica D: Nonlinear Phenomena 200.3 (2005): 205-219.

This problem is also studied in graph theory community under "graph partitioning".

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a definition of graph connectivity for undirected graphs. One can try to generalize the idea of [Fiedler vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_connectivity) from directed graphs: if the second-to-last singular value of $I-P$ is zero, then the matrix is "splittable", otherwise it is not. For instance, you can use the ratio $\sigma_{n-1}/\sigma_1$ as a measure of connectivity.

If you have already a candidate approximate splitting into two blocks $\begin{bmatrix}P_{11} & P_{12} \\ P_{21} & P_{22}\end{bmatrix}$, another simple performance measure is $\frac{\|P_{12}\|+\|P_{21}\|}{\|P_{11}\|+\|P_{12}\|+\|P_{21}\|+\|P_{22}\|}$, which also makes sense as "distance from the closest splittable matrix".

Comment: Thanks. I'd taught of the Fiedler eigenvalue of the weighted graph associated with my Markov chain, but for some reason, declined it thinking it would be a very loose measure of this "splittability". Maybe not, after all. Thanks for the suggestion.